# How do i achieve this result in MysQL with a single Query

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to count how many times the code is repeated in each query without the last 3 letters.
The capital letters in the code column is what i need.

| IDs | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 58112 | DFGH dds |
| 25554 | JIIK sdf |
| 58112 | ABCD klo |
| 21122 | DFGH pdo |
| 58000 | KPSD jsi |
| 94588 | ABCD rtu |

I tried this

```
Select IDs, Code, 
    COUNT(case when code LIKE CONCAT(LEFT(code,char_length(code)-3, '%') then 1 else 0 end) as samecode) 
from tbl  
group by IDs;
```

it returned this

| IDs | Code | samecode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 58112 | DFGH dds | 1 |
| 25554 | JIIK sdf | 1 |
| 58112 | ABCD klo | 1 |
| 21122 | DFGH pdo | 1 |
| 58000 | KPSD jsi | 1 |
| 94588 | ABCD rtu | 1 |

what i expected it to return is

| IDs | Code | samecode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 58112 | DFGH dds | 2 |
| 25554 | JIIK sdf | 1 |
| 58112 | ABCD klo | 2 |
| 21122 | DFGH pdo | 2 |
| 58000 | KPSD jsi | 1 |
| 94588 | ABCD rtu | 2 |

Comment: You want `SUM()`, not `COUNT()`. `COUNT()` counts the number of non-null values, so it counts `1` and `0` the same.

Comment: I don't think the result you show could be what you actually got. `GROUP BY IDs` means there should be only one row for each IDs, but you have two rows with `IDs = 58112`.

Comment: You also have a syntax error, you're missing the `)` for `LEFT(`

Answer (score 0):

Use a self-join that joins with elements that have the same prefix in `code`.

```
SELECT t1.IDs, t1.code, COUNT(*) AS samecode
FROM tbl AS t1
JOIN tbl AS t2 ON LEFT(t1.code, char_length(t1.code)-3) = LEFT(t2.code, char_length(t2.code)-3)
GROUP BY t1.IDs, t1.code
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pkdRUBH4gGfCDVUJrhu2pY/0)

Comment: The IDs are different too, what the OP wants in the example looks like double counting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to get the first set of characters in `Code`:

```
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(Code,' ',1)
```

Then use `COUNT() OVER ()` to do the counting:

```
       COUNT(Code) OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(Code,' ',1))
```

The final query should look something like this:

```
SELECT IDs, Code,
       COUNT(Code) OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(Code,' ',1)) AS samecode
FROM tbl
```

There's a slightly different code in the [demo fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/saMH8c-2)

For older MySQL that don't have `COUNT() OVER ()` functionality, I can think of at least two way.

1. Using derived table to get the count then `LEFT JOIN` with the main table:

```
SELECT IDs, Code,
       tCnt AS samecode
FROM tbl t1
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(Code,' ',1) xCode, COUNT(*) AS tCnt
       FROM tbl 
       GROUP BY xcode) t2
  ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.Code,' ',1)=t2.xCode;
```

OR

2. Using correlated sub-query in `SELECT`:

```
SELECT IDs, Code,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM tbl t2 WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.Code,' ',1)=SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.Code,' ',1)
       GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.Code,' ',1)) AS samecode
FROM tbl t1;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pvAGwKJu)

Comment: Thank you very much,  your solution helped me solved the problem,  although i am currently using mysql 5.7